# Additive duality of character of a local fields

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, characters, langlands-program

I am studying "the local Langlands conjecture for GL(2)" of Bushnell and Henniart. I am having a hard time getting into the mechanics. And I have some problems with one of the first proposition.

Let $F$ be a local field, let $ \widehat{F}$ be the group of characters of $F$. Now, let $\psi \in \widehat{F}$ be a non trivial character of level $d$. So we have

1. Let $a \in F$. The map $a\psi: x \mapsto \psi(ax)$ is a character of $F$ and if $a\neq 0$ then the character $a\psi$ has level $d-v_F(x)$.
2. The map $a \mapsto a\psi$ is a group isomorphism $F \cong \widehat{F}$

It's clear to me that $a\psi$ is a character and that its level is $d-v_F(x)$, this is an obvious consequence of
$$
x \in \ker(a\psi) \iff ax \in \ker{\psi}.
$$
After that I have two problems with the isomorphism. The book says that $a \mapsto a\psi$ is an injective group homomorphism without proof. But it is difficult to me to accept this fact.

$a\psi=b\psi$ if and only if they agree on $x$ for all $x \in F$. So
$$
\psi(ax)=\psi(bx) \qquad \forall x \in F
$$
that is equivalent to
$$
ax\equiv bx \bmod  \ker\psi \qquad \forall x \in F
$$
that is the same of
$$
a\equiv b  \bmod \ker\psi 
$$
So
$$a\psi=b\psi \iff a\equiv b \bmod \ker\psi
$$
that is clearly not the same of the book, so I am wrong. But why? And why this is an injective map?

The other problem is with the second part of the proof.

Let $w$ be a uniformizer of $F$ and let $\mathfrak{o}$ be the valuation ring of $F$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.
If we take another non trivial character $\theta \in \widehat{F}$ with level $l$, clearly $uw^{d-l}\psi$ has level $l$ for all $u \in \mathfrak{o}^\times$. So $uw^{d-l}\psi$ and $\theta$ agree on $\mathfrak{p}^l$. But now, if we take $u,u' \in \mathfrak{o}^\times$, then $uw^{d-l}\psi$ and $u'w^{d-l}\psi$ agree on $\mathfrak{p}^{l-1}$ if and only if $u \equiv u' \bmod\mathfrak{p}$. It's not obvious how I can compute this.

Some hint to these two problems?

Comment: Write congruences using \bmod as your "mod" command. It always gives good spacing without any need to use \quad or other tricks to force extra spacing.  And kernels in math mode are \ker, not $Ker$ (ugly italics).

Answer (score 0):

You said $\psi$ is nontrivial.

Rewrite $\psi(ax) = \psi(bx)$ as
$1 = \psi(ax)\psi(bx)^{-1} = \psi(ax - bx) = \psi((a-b)x)$. This holds when $x$ runs over your local field, so unless $a = b$, we get $\psi(y) = 1$ for all $y$ in the field: $\psi$ is trivial. That contradicts the assumption that $\psi$ is nontrivial, so $a = b$.

Your mistake is that it is *not* true that the condition $ax \equiv bx \bmod \ker \psi$ for all $x$ in the field is equivalent to $a \equiv b \bmod \ker \psi$. That would be saying $(a-b)F \subset \ker \psi$ is equivalent to $a-b \in \ker \psi$. Do you see those are not generally equivalent?